# Dalvik Virtual Machine build target

Tags: debugging, build, dalvik

I am new to Android platform and Dalvik VM. I have some questions about debugging the Dalvik VM.

1. How to debug Dalvik VM on an emulator?
2. I build Android by using full-eng as the target

   source build/envsetup.sh
   lunch full-eng

   I am wondering how to build and debug a DVM targeted on host X86 machine instead of Android emulator or real device. I did some search online and find the target is called sim-eng. My Android version (JellyBean) does not have this lunch target option:

You're building on Darwin

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. vbox_x86-eng
     4. full_grouper-userdebug
     5. mini_armv7a_neon-userdebug
     6. mini_armv7a-userdebug
     7. full_wingray-userdebug
     8. full_crespo-userdebug
     9. full_maguro-userdebug
     10. full_panda-userdebug

Does anyone know how to build/debug on host target??

Answer (score 1):

The sim-eng target hasn't been supported for several releases.  It was never officially supported at all, really, so having a fully-working simulator build in AOSP was pretty rare.

The good news is that Dalvik VM is used by the Android build system, so if you can build the full Android tree for any target, you'll have a working copy on the desktop for free.  In recent versions of Android (4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich and later), a copy of the `dalvik` script will be installed in your path ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/vm/dalvik)), and can be executed directly.

```
dalvik -help foo
```